# Convert a series of string into a series of statements

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to apply this setup:

```
col         = 'consumption_energy'
conditions  = [ df2[col] >= 400, (df2[col] < 400) & (df2[col]> 200), df2[col] <= 200 ]
choices     = [ "high", 'medium', 'low' ]

df2["energy_class"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
```

but I have the conditions loaded in a dataframe that is read from a csv file, so the object conditions looks more like:

```
conditions=['df2[col]>=400','(df2[col] < 400) & (df2[col]> 200)', 'df2[col] <= 200']
```

how can I convert them so python interprets it as an actual conditional?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use python [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) or try [`pandas.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) on the condition.

Comment: `eval(conditions[0])` <----- This is how you will use it.

Comment: If it's always conditions like that, instead use `pd.cut` so you can save the cutpoints [-inf, 200, 400, inf] and the labels ['low', 'medium', 'high']. Simple enough to read those from a file.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I try to convert it like conditions=pd.eval(conditions_strings) it throws an error: should be boolean ndarray

Answer (score 0):

For this You can use `eval` Refer: [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but when I try to convert it like conditions=pd.eval(conditions_strings) it throws an error: should be boolean ndarray

Comment: you are giving list as a parameter, which you should not do

Comment: If my answer solves your problem mark it as an answer

Comment: thanks, but it didn't answer the question. I used another way to get the result which is not to execute the code but rather assign it for later evaluation (as condition in a loop). Thanks for your time